# Handling large long values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently implement a 2D plot which shall be used to relate those two values to a visual "landscape":

- x-axis: huge binary discrete values with a length of up to
  3000 digits (2^3000)
- y-axis: calculated value (no problem)

It seems that matplotlib can not handle such huge values.
As it represents a landscape, the values itself are not important. What is important is a visual representation of the function itself.
I tried to log-scale the values, which did not solve the problem. This is the current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''
convert binary list to gray code to maintain hamming distance
'''
def indtogray(self, ind):
    return ind[:1] + [i ^ ishift for i, ishift in zip(ind[:-1], ind[1:])]

'''
Create int from gray value
'''
def graytoint(self, gray):
    i = 0
    for bit in gray:
        i = i*2 + bit
    return i

'''
Create example list of binary lists
'''
def create(self, n, size):
    return [[np.random.randint(2) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(n)]

def showPlot(self, toolbox, neval):
    individuals = self.create(100, 2000)
    fitnesses = map(np.sum, individuals)

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    values = map(self.graytoint, map(self.indtogray, individuals))
    full = zip(*sorted(zip(values, fitnesses)))
    line = ax.plot(full[0], full[1], 'r-')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show()
```

I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error just means that your number is too big and it cannot convert it to float. Things you can do is take the logarithm of x.

Now if you have up to 3000 binary digits, this means that the largest decimal number is `pow(2,3000)`. If you take `log(pow(2,3000)`, you should get 2079.44154~ which you should then be able convert to a float. I would double check to see if the number you have is in binary format but in decimal representation. Meaning if `x[0] = 10`, make sure that it is ten and not 2 in binary. Otherwise, a 2^3000 number in binary format would be very large.

Comment: interesting that numpy seems also not to be able to handle large numbers: np.log10(pow(2,2000)) -> AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'log10' whereas pythons math is able to do it.